# Cannot create new item in manual save mode database

Tags: google-app-maker

Trying to replicate some of the functions of the Project Tracker template, so I am using a Datasource in Manual Save Mode.

When I try to create a new item I get the following error:

> Cannot create a new record on a datasource in manual save mode with
>   pending changes.

I tried creating a button and clicking "`widget.datasource.clearChanges();`" but that doesn't seem to help.

I am not sure how to clear the pending changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured it out/figured out a work around.

I adjusted all my buttons (ex: my Add Item button, my Delete button, etc.) by adding `"widget.datasource.saveChanges();"` to them. So now it looks like this:

```
widget.datasource.saveChanges(); 
app.showDialog(app.pageFragments.Add);
```

And this:

```
widget.datasource.saveChanges();
app.closeDialog();
```